# Disable highlighting in location list in vim

Tags: highlighting

I've found many questions about disabling search highlighting in vim, but couldn't find the way to disable highlighting in location list.
[image]

As you can see, yellow highlighting is shown on the first line inside location list.

I want to disable it.

Could someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: that first line is a cursor that you can move with the up/down arrow, or j/k. You can then press <return> to jump to that said location. Due to that I would not recommend to not highlight the cursor.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I understand it's useful to jump to the said location, but my question was is there a way to disable the highlighting. Can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The highlight rule you are looking for should be `QuickFixLine`.

So disabling the background would be done in your `.vimrc` with:

```
highlight QuickFixLine ctermbg=none
```

Comment: Note that this does not alter the ability to jump to a location from the location/quickfix window.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. The ability to jump to the said location with no highlighting. Thank you.